# How can I change this method to get rid of the warning without anything changing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So this question:[Warning-used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247315/warning-used-as-the-name-of-the-previous-parameter-rather-than-as-part-of-the-se)

answers part of my problem, but I really don't want anything to change inside this method and I'm a bit confused on how this works. Here's the whole method:

```
-(void) SetRightWrong:(sqzWord *)word: (int) rightWrong
{
if (self.mastered==nil) {
    self.mastered = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
}

//if right change number right
if (rightWrong == 1) {
    word.numberCorrect++;
     //if 3 right move to masterd list

    [self.onDeck removeObject:word];
    if(word.numberCorrect >= 3 )
    {
        [self.mastered addObject:word];


    }
    else
    {
         //if not 3 right move to end of ondeck
        [self.onDeck addObject:word];

    }


}
else if(rightWrong == 0)
{
    //if wrong remove one from number right unless 0
    NSUInteger i;

    i=[self.onDeck indexOfObject:word];

    word = [self.onDeck objectAtIndex:i];

    if (word.numberCorrect >0) {
         word.numberCorrect--;
    }
}
}
```

The warning I am getting is: 'word' used as the name of the previous parameter than as part of the selector.

Comment: You *have* to change your method name, there is no avoiding that. You need to make the method similar to: `-(void) setRightWrong:(sqzWord *)word withInt:(int)rightWrong` Where `word` is your `sqzWord` pointer, and `rightWrong` is your integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you haven't given a name to the first argument of the method. As it stands right now, you have the following:

```
-(void) SetRightWrong:(sqzWord *)word: (int) rightWrong
```

Where `rightWrong` is the name of the `word:` argument, but there is no name for the `SetRightWrong` argument. You should give the first parameter a name, immediately following its type (`sqzWord *`).

```
-(void)setRightWrong:(sqzWord *)aWord   word:(int)rightWrong;
   (1)     (2)           (3)     (4)     (5)   (6)  (7)
```

1. Return Type
2. First part of method name
3. Parameter type
4. First parameter
5. Seceond part of method name
6. Parameter type
7. Second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what the problem actually is? You are saying you are confused a bit. So you are confused, you get a warning, which should clearly tell you that there is a problem, and instead of trying to fix the problem, you want help how to get rid of the warning? That is a deeply worrying attitude in a programmer.

To fix your problem: Download some Objective-C sample code. *Any* sample code. Look at how Objective-C methods are named. Compare it to how your Objective-C method is named. If you can't see the difference, look at it again tomorrow, and before you look at it say to yourself: "My code is wrong. The compiler is right. My task is to find why my code is wrong. "